# How to add more data into an exisitng data using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.9, jquery-data

How can I add more data into an exisitng data using jquery - or just plain javascript?

```
fd = {
    name : file_data.name,
    size : file_data.size
};

// And others.
$("form").find('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
    $(fd).data(this.name, this.value);
});
```

I get this strange result,

```
Array
(
    [name] => Dangerous Man.mp3
    [size] => 11912748
    [jQuery1910560199169432603] => Array
        (
            [toJSON] => undefined
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [article_id] => 
                    [category_id] => 15
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [max_upload_filesize] => 3
                    [method] => upload
                    [required[category_id] => Category ID
                )

        )

)
```

But I am after this result,

```
Array
(
    [name] => Dangerous Man.mp3
    [size] => 11912748
    [article_id] => 1
    [category_id] => 15
    [user_id] => 1
    [max_upload_filesize] => 3
    [method] => upload
    [required[category_id] => Category ID

)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add property to object

```
$("form").find('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
    fd[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass only Element, NodeList, selector or a function into $ function, not an Object.
You shoud do it this way :

```
fb[ this.name ] = this.value;
```

instead of

```
$(fd).data(this.name, this.value);
```

Comment: thanks but it removes my existing data of `fd = {
                                                name : file_data.name,
                                                size : file_data.size
                                            };`

Comment: that is because there are hidden input fields with names 'name' and 'size'. if you could move the assignment of name and size properties of fd object after the itteration, that would work.